# How to interpolate spatial data from irregular grid to regular grid using the max of the k-nearest neighbours?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, spatial, scipy-spatial

I am having a problem struggeling me for a few days now. :

There are 17 numpy arrays with values and corresponding latitude and longitude coordinates. Each of the them contains 360*600 points. These points are overlappping at some parts. What I want to do in the end is to have a composite of the data at one regular grid.

With the common `scipy.interpolate.griddata` function I am having the problem that in these overlapping regions I am having different values often. This results in strange artefacts you can see in the first image:

[image]

My first idea is to take the max value of the values used in the interpolation. 
I have found out that `scipy.interpolate.griddata` uses triangulation to interpolate but actually I can't find a pipeline that I can adapt.

I hope you can understand that I do not share any code bc. dataset is huge and my question is more about to find the best practice or receive some interesting ideas to solve this problem. Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe calculate first the distance matrix between your regular grid points (`x` and the existing irregular ones `y`:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html

Then, for each point, find the indices of the `k` smallest distances and take the maximum value of the value on the irregular grid.

Disclamer: I don't know how it scales - and what your requirements are regarding performance.

Edit: You might be able to pre-eliminate data-sets for specific regions, to minimise the effort to calculate all the distance matrices.